# Bash log monitoring

Tags: bash, logging, awk

I've made a Bash script to monitor some server log files for certain data and my method probably isn't the most efficient.

One section specifically bugs me is that I have to write a newline to the monitored log so that the same line wont be read over continually.

Feedback would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

serverlog=/home/skay/NewWorld/server.log
onlinefile=/home/skay/website/log/online.log
offlinefile=/home/skay/website/log/offline.log
index=0

# Creating the file
if [ ! -f "$onlinefile" ]; then
    touch $onlinefile
    echo "Name                  Date            Time" >> "$onlinefile"
fi
if [ ! -f "$offlinefile" ]; then
    touch $offlinefile
    echo "Name                  Date            Time" >> "$offlinefile"
fi

# Functions
function readfile {

# Login Variables
loginplayer=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "joined the game" | awk '{print $4}'`
logintime=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "joined the game" | awk '{print $2}'`
logindate=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "joined the game" | awk '{print $1}'`

# Logout Variables
logoutplayer=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "left the game" | awk '{print $4}'`
logouttime=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "left the game" | awk '{print $2}'`
logoutdate=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "left the game" | awk '{print $1}'`

# Check for Player Login
    if [ ! -z "$loginplayer" ]; then
        echo "$loginplayer          $logindate  $logintime" >> "$onlinefile"
        echo "Player $loginplayer login detected" >> "$serverlog"
        line=`grep -rne "$loginplayer" $offlinefile | cut -d':' -f1`
        if [ "$line" > 1 ]; then
            sed -i "$line"d $offlinefile
            unset loginplayer
                    unset line
        fi
    fi
# Check for Player Logout
    if [ ! -z "$logoutplayer" ]; then
        echo "$logoutplayer         $logoutdate $logouttime" >> "$offlinefile"
        echo "Player $loginplayer logout detected" >> "$serverlog"
        line=`grep -rne "$logoutplayer" $onlinefile | cut -d':' -f1`
        if [ "$line" > 1 ]; then
            sed -i "$line"d $onlinefile
            unset logoutplayer
            unset line
        fi
    fi
}

# Loop
while [ $index -lt 100 ]; do
    readfile
done
```

Comment: A minor remark: I think `! -z` is equivalent to `-n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your goal is to monitor `$serverlog` continuously, and update `$onlinefile` and `$offlinefile` accordingly.  The fact that you repeatedly close and reopen `$serverlog` is problematic, not only for performance reasons, but as you remarked, you risk processing the same line endlessly.  Therefore, your general strategy should be to keep the file open, like this:

```
tail -f "$serverlog" | do_all_processing_here
```

Note that `grep "[INFO]"` doesn't do what you intend; instead, it matches lines that contain any of the characters `I`, `N`, `F`, or `O`.  You probably meant `grep -F '[INFO]'` — the `-F` causes `grep` to treat your pattern as a fixed string rather than a regular expression.  Then, your structure would be:

```
tail -f "$serverlog" | grep -F '[INFO]' | do_more_processing_here
```

I'm going to guess that `[INFO]` would appear in the third field of your server log.  If so, the efficient solution would be…

```
tail -f "$serverlog" | \
while read date time severity player message ; do
    case "$severity" in
      \[INFO\])
        case "$message" in
          *joined the game*)
            echo "$player    $date  $time" >> "$onlinefile"
            sed -i -e "$(
                awk -v player="$player" '$1 == player { print NR "d;"}' "$offlinefile"
            )" "$offlinefile"
            ;;
          *left the game*)
            echo "$player    $date  $time" >> "$offlinefile"
            sed -i -e "$(
                awk -v player="$player" '$1 == player { print NR "d;"}' "$onlinefile"
            )" "$onlinefile"
            ;;
        esac # case $message
        ;;
    esac # case $severity
done
```

It's also possible to skip `awk` and edit `$offlinefile` and `$onlinefile` directly with

```
sed -i "/^$player /d" "$offlinefile"
```

but there could be a vulnerability if `$player` contained special characters such as `.*`.  [A better solution, if you have GNU awk ≥ 4.1.0](//stackoverflow.com/q/16529716/1157100), is

```
awk -v player="$player" '$1 != player' -i inplace "$offlinefile"
```

With other versions of `awk`, you could use `tempfile` to help you perform the edit.

Answer (score 2):

I have small suggestions for the function readfile to reduce the number of shell commands you need to run :

1. Save the output of the following into a variable so it can be reused as shown in #2:

   ```
   last_line=$(tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]")
   ```
2. As you are already using awk, use it to search and select columns both:

   ```
   login_time=$(echo $last_line | awk '/joined the game/ {print $2}')
   ```
3. Since you are searching in a single file and not recursively, the -r flag to grep can be removed.